# What is falling off the Saturn V at launch?

Tags: launch, saturn-v

At 4:07 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cOhZy7dhTo) you can see that large objects are falling of the outside of the rocket. What are those?

Comment: Welcome to space! Your question has been asked and answered before, so it will be closed as a duplicate. It's ice BTW.